# my link not working anymore in yii

Tags: url, yii, syntax-error

I cannot access to the 'view' page of only 1 PaymentController in my modules Setup

It still work on localhost, but don't know why not in my live site. I have tried many like: http://vn2t.net/setup/payment/view/9.html or vn2t.net/setup/payment/view/id/9.html,... but always get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   /home/u231459264/public_html/protected/modules/setup/views/payment/view.php
>   on line 130

Meanwhile, other Controller like User: http://vn2t.net/setup/user/view/4.html or News: vn2t.net/setup/news/view/1.html,... still working

I even tried to remove Url rules in config/main.php but still not work

Comment: Can you post the `payment/view.php` file? (include line 130)

Comment: This is my actionView:

`public function actionView($id) {

        $order = Order::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("id_payment" => $id));

        $this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
            'order' => $order,
        ));
    }`

Comment: I mean your view file. Action seems correct, that error says the problem is your view file.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>/css/cart.css"/>`
` // breadcrumbs and CMenu`
`<h1>Thông tin đơn hàng #<?php echo $model->id_hoadon; ?></h1>`
`<?php
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('id_hoadon')); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->id_hoadon); ?></td>
    </tr>
....... // i only use infomation from $model in there
</table>`
`....
<?php
    $items = 0;
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($order as $key => $value) {`
`//a div use info from $value
`<?php } ?>

Comment: `<?php
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::button('Xóa đơn hàng', array('class' => 'cartLeftButton button')), array(
    'payment/delete',
    'id' => $model->id_hoadon
        ), array('submit' => array(
        'payment/delete',
        'id' => $model->id_hoadon
    ), 'confirm' => 'Bạn có chắc chắn muốn xóa đơn hàng?'));
?>
<?php
if ($model->xuly == "Chưa xử lý"):
    ?>
    <button onclick="xuly()" class="cartRightButton button">Đánh dấu đã xử lý</button>
    <?php
endif;
?>
`

Comment: This is the last
`<script>
    function xuly() {
        var baseUrl = "<? = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#xuly").text("Đã xử lý");
            $.post(baseUrl + "/setup/payment/done?id=" +<?= $model->id_hoadon ?>, function (data) {
            });
        });
    }
</script>
`

Comment: Right, can you tell me where is the line **130**?

Comment: it only has 123 line :(

Comment: does maybe my hosting have problem? because it's still work on localhost Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the problem is related to parsing your view file. I correct some mistakes inside your view file. Your view file(beginning from `foreach`) should be change to this:

```
<?php foreach($order as $key => $value): ?> 
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::button('XÃ³a Ä‘Æ¡n hÃ ng', 
        array('class' => 'cartLeftButton button')),
        array('payment/delete', 'id' => $model->id_hoadon),
        array('submit' => array('payment/delete', 'id' => $model->id_hoadon),
           'confirm' => 'Báº¡n cÃ³ cháº¯c cháº¯n muá»‘n xÃ³a Ä‘Æ¡n hÃ ng?'));

     if($model->xuly == "ChÆ°a xá»­ lÃ½"): ?> 
         <button onclick="xuly()" class="cartRightButton button">Ä�Ã¡nh dáº¥u Ä‘Ã£ xá»­ lÃ½</button> 
     <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your recommend for my error (relating to parsing my view file), i have found out what error in my view file. It's because this line:
`<script> function xuly() { var baseUrl = "<? = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>"; ....`
it should be <?= instead of <? = . Thank you very much again